# Submitting instance of class as a parameter

Tags: java

Say I had the following code

```
class A {      
    int x = 4;
    public void x() {
         /* */
         B myB = new B(/*paramter here*/);
    }
}
```

Is it possible to submit the current instance of A as a paramter to the constructor of B?

Comment: *Is it possible to submit the current instance of A as a parameter to the constructor of B?* - Yes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

to pass the current instance use

```
B myB = new B(this);
```

For your acknowledgement. From [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html)

> Within an instance method or a constructor, this is a reference to the
>   current object — the object whose method or constructor is being
>   called. You can refer to any member of the current object from within
>   an instance method or a constructor by using this.